# Windows licence type to run a SQL server

Tags: sql-server, licensing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing question?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-question)

What is Minimum Windows Server licence to run a SQL server for use in a web farm.
Can I run a SQL on a Server2008 Web edition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MSDN website has a detailed description of all the Operating System requirements for the various editions of SQL Server 2008 from the Express right through the Data Center editions.  The requirements for the OS change as you move through the versions.  Express will run on consumer operating systems, but it appears that most of the versions of Windows Server have a corresponding edition of SQL Server 2008.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the SQL Server version and license type, from "Standard" to "Enterprise."

The latest version, SQL Server 2008, runs as "Standard" even on Windows XP Service Pack 2. The minimum Windows Server version is Windows Server 2003 (with SP2).

SQL Server 2008 Enterprise requires a Server operating system, Windows Server 2003 or 2008.

Windows Server **2008** Web allows you to install all versions of SQL Server 2008, while you can only install **SQL Server Express** on the Windows Server **2003** *Web Edition* (SP2). It has some limitations:

- CPUs: Only 1 CPU. If a system has more than 1 SQL Server Express 2008 will still run but limit itself to one CPU
- RAM: 1 GB. More RAM can exist, but SQL Server Express 2008 will use only 1 GB
- Database Size: maximum 4 GB

Comment: "You can only install SQL Server Express on the Windows Server 2003/2008 Web Edition (SP2). "

Not if you read the link from kdmurray 
SQL Server 2008 Standard (64-bit) x64
The following table shows system requirements for SQL Server 2008 Standard (64-bit) x64:
Operating system: Windows Server 2008 x64 Web
With the note: 
Management Tools are supported in WOW64, a feature of 64-bit editions of Microsoft Windows that enables 32-bit applications to execute natively in 32-bit mode.

Comment: You are right, I wasn't aware that this changed in Windows Server 2008. I updated my answer. Thank you very much!

Comment: NP, tanks for answering, we all learn new tings each day =) /Kalle